# KDE writing (too many) in the console

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, qtgui, qfiledialog

I'm developping a Qt GUI application.

My problem is that I use the console for another thread (it write his comunication in it), and the main problem is that when I create a QFileDialog (in order to select a script file), KDE is wrinting useless  informations (for me at least).

Is there a way to remove all possibility from my QFileDialog to write anything into the consolethat ? Is there a trick to switch main output to another (useless) target ?

My code (but I don't think it's really gonna help you) :

```
void MyGUI::setPathWithFileExplorer()
{
  QFileDialog dlg;
  dlg.resize(320,240);
  QString fileName = dlg.getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open script file"), "~/", tr("Script Files (*.js)"));

  if(fileName != "")
    ui->editScriptPath->setText(fileName);
}
```

Output :

> kded(21003) Mollet::KioSlaveNotifier::onDirectoryEntered: "trash:/"
>   kded(21003) Mollet::KioSlaveNotifier::onDirectoryLeft: "trash:/"
>   kded(21003) Mollet::KioSlaveNotifier::onDirectoryEntered:
>   "file://[PATH TO MY USER FOLDER]" kded(21003)
>   Mollet::KioSlaveNotifier::onDirectoryLeft:
>   "file://[PATH TO MY USER FOLDER]" kded(21003)
>   Mollet::KioSlaveNotifier::onDirectoryEntered:
>   "file://[PATH TO MY USER FOLDER]" kfilemodule(21676)
>   KSambaSharePrivate::testparmParamValue: We got some errors while
>   running testparm "Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
>   Loaded services file OK. WARNING: The setting 'security=ads' should
>   NOT be combined with the 'password server' parameter. (by default
>   Samba will discover the correct DC to contact automatically). WARNING:
>   You have some share names that are longer than 12 characters. These
>   may not be accessible to some older clients. (Eg. Windows9x,
>   WindowsMe, and smbclient prior to Samba 3.0.) "
>   QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed:
>   Permission non accordée QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths:
>   /var/lib/samba/usershares

Comment: What exactly does QFileDialog print to debug?

Comment: Yeah, is it warning or regular messages? OT: `fileName != ""` should be `!fileName.isEmpty()`. You could work this around by writing into file rather than output, and "tail" that file in another console.

Comment: @hank: what exactly do you mean by debug? I do not see the OP mentioning debug just yet.

Comment: With whom is your other thread communicating? I'd rather use a separate pipe/socket etc. in a UI application, rather than stdout.

Comment: I believe if you use the release rather than the debug Qt libraries, the Qt chatter will go away. (You may have to manually tweak your settings in your project/makefile to link these in. Drop the "d" off the libraries.)

Comment: @LaszloPapp I'll change the fileName statement, thanks, how can I do write into a file ? I still need the output of my other thread (comming from the same main program), is it possible to write into a file only GUI output ?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld My other thread is used to comunicate with an embedded linux system. It print sended and received message into my console. This is why I don't want the 'polution' of QFileDialog

Comment: @hank I've edited my post with the non-wanted output

Comment: That’s output from KDE, not from Qt.

Comment: @TimothéeBéhéty: your problem is actually _KDE_, not Qt. KDE is really spammy inherently; I always disliked it. I recommend to update the title accordingly as it is confusing right now. I would just write the log into a file - as it may be useful anyway -, and would monitor that in a separate console. You could even use the new logger in 5.2.

Comment: @TimothéeBéhéty: run kdebugdialog and deselect all alternatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `kdebugdialog` and then `Deselect All`. Here you can see an inline screenshot on my machine.

[image]

Failing that, you could always use `QFile` to log your output into a dedicated file, and then monitor that in a separate prompt or application.

If you go down that way, you could even take a look at the logger functionality added in 5.2 if you happen to be able to use that version.

Comment: It works thanks.
For the logger part, I'm unfortunately using and have to use Qt 4.8.1.

Comment: That will only fix the issue locally, so not a good solution if you want to deploy the program and the other thread uses stdout/stderr for critical functionality. But really, relying on them being clean is dangerous and should be avoided.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: we do not know the exact use case, hence see the text after the screenshot for an IMO reasonable fallback option if the kde setting does not suffice.

Comment: I've totally unchecked all kdebugdialog. I'm not interested of whatever it is saying to me.

Comment: @TimothéeBéhéty: yes, you can even use the `Disable all debug output option`. Note that there might be some kde software not respecting these settings, but it should be the rarity, hopefully.